# Verifying generic method called using Moq

Tags: c#, moq, verify

I'm having trouble verifying that mock of `IInterface.SomeMethod<T>(T arg)` was called using `Moq.Mock.Verify`.

I'm can verify that method was called on a "Standard" interface either using `It.IsAny<IGenericInterface>()` or `It.IsAny<ConcreteImplementationOfIGenericInterface>()`, and I have no troubles verifying a generic method call using `It.IsAny<ConcreteImplementationOfIGenericInterface>()`, but I can't verify a generic method was called using `It.IsAny<IGenericInterface>()` - it always says that the method was not called and the unit test fails.

Here is my unit test:

```
public void TestMethod1()
{
    var mockInterface = new Mock<IServiceInterface>();

    var classUnderTest = new ClassUnderTest(mockInterface.Object);

    classUnderTest.Run();

    // next three lines are fine and pass the unit tests
    mockInterface.Verify(serviceInterface => serviceInterface.NotGenericMethod(It.IsAny<ConcreteSpecificCommand>()), Times.Once());
    mockInterface.Verify(serviceInterface => serviceInterface.NotGenericMethod(It.IsAny<ISpecificCommand>()), Times.Once());
    mockInterface.Verify(serviceInterface => serviceInterface.GenericMethod(It.IsAny<ConcreteSpecificCommand>()), Times.Once());

    // this line breaks: "Expected invocation on the mock once, but was 0 times"
    mockInterface.Verify(serviceInterface => serviceInterface.GenericMethod(It.IsAny<ISpecificCommand>()), Times.Once());
}
```

Here is my class under test:

```
public class ClassUnderTest
{
    private IServiceInterface _service;

    public ClassUnderTest(IServiceInterface service)
    {
        _service = service;
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        var command = new ConcreteSpecificCommand();
        _service.GenericMethod(command);
        _service.NotGenericMethod(command);
    }
}
```

Here is my `IServiceInterface`:

```
public interface IServiceInterface
{
    void NotGenericMethod(ISpecificCommand command);
    void GenericMethod<T>(T command);
}
```

And here is my interface/class inheritance hierarchy:

```
public interface ISpecificCommand
{
}

public class ConcreteSpecificCommand : ISpecificCommand
{
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a known issue in the Moq 4.0.10827 which is a current release version. See this discussion at GitHub https://github.com/Moq/moq4/pull/25. I have downloaded its dev branch, compiled and referenced it and now your test passes.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to wing it.  Since `GenericMethod<T>` requires that a T argument be provided, would it be possible to do:

```
mockInterface.Verify(serviceInterface => serviceInterface.GenericMethod(It.Is<object>(x=> typeof(ISpecificCommand).IsAssignableFrom(x.GetType()))), Times.Once());
```