# Mocking Entity Framwork using Moq not returning DbSet<T>

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, moq

I have a DbSet which I have mocked and exposed. I have filled some departments to the context. NOw when I access those Departments, I get null.

```
    private Mock<DbSet<Department>> departmentSet;
    private Mock<DemoEntities> context;

    [TestInitializeAttribute()]
    public void TestInit()
    {
        context = new Mock<DemoEntities>();
        departmentSet = new Mock<DbSet<Department>>();
        context.Setup(c => c.Departments).Returns(departmentSet.Object);
        context.Object.Departments.Add(new Department() { Name = "HR", Id = 1 });
        context.Object.Departments.Add(new Department() { Name = "Operations", Id = 2 });


        context.Object.SaveChanges();

        var list = context.Object.Departments; //returns null
     }
```

Can anyone please let me know what I am doing wrong. As the rest of the test cases depend on accessing context.Object.Departments.

Comment: I believe you have to use it like this: `context.Object.Departments.ToList()`

Comment: If I put ToList(), it throws null pointer exception.

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38748666/mocking-dbcontext-in-entity-framework-6-1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to mock the `.Set<>` as below

```
 private static Mock<DbSet<T>> GetDbSetMock<T>(IEnumerable<T> items = null) where T : class
        {
            if (items == null)
            {
                items = new T[0];
            }

            var dbSetMock = new Mock<DbSet<T>>();
            var q = dbSetMock.As<IQueryable<T>>();

            q.Setup(x => x.GetEnumerator()).Returns(items.GetEnumerator);

            return dbSetMock;
        }



var mockContext = new Mock<MyDbContext>();

var users = new List<User> { new User { Email = "my@email.com", Id = 1 } };

mockContext.Setup(x => x.Set<User>()).Returns(GetDbSetMock(users).Object);
```

Comment: context.Setup(x => x.Departments).Returns(GetDbSetMock(departments).Object);                                        Fixed it. Thank you